# How to add onclick function to a table created inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOBzH.jpg)Am fetching json data from api and display it in table and i need to add a button to each row onclick function will get the row value as parameters and request for a get method.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("gfgdetails.json", function (data) {
    var student = "";
    // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
      //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
      student += "";
      student += "" + value.GFGUserName + "";
      student += "" + value.NoOfProblems + "";
      student += "" + value.TotalScore + "";
      student += "" + value.Articles + "";
      student += "";
    }); //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE
    $("#table").append(student);
  });
});
```

[Example source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fetch-data-from-json-file-and-display-in-html-table-using-jquery/)

I need a button inside a td.

Comment: Note: your source link builds HTML (`<td>` etc) and appends it but you're just appending text, so won't insert a row in your table.  If `#table` is a `<table>` then your text won't be in the table.   As such as you don't have any "rows" so you can't add a button.   If you do add `<td>` etc then include `<button>` html (with a class) within your "student" html - and use event delegation to add the click handler against that class (don't use `id=`)

Comment: My requirement is getting json data from api and display in table and if i click on perticular data(username)it should show all the details of that user.